# Asp.net MVC 5 and Angular 2: Get Authenticate in both side from Angular

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-mvc-5, angular-cli

Currently, I'm working on a project that needs to be merged their back-end and front-end. the back-end is written in asp.net MVC 5 with jwt authentication mechanism, and front-end written in angular 4 with jwt mechanism.

My issue is I need to get authenticate from front-end side which is angular and can go to an old part of the project that is written in asp.net MVC 5 and Razor view.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution:

Get authenticate from ASP.net and add the authentication info into the cookies and then access it from angular